How do you toggle query params with multiple checkboxes in HTMX?
I want to make checkboxes that toggle different query parameters.
e.g.

1st checkbox toggles ulid=000
2nd checkbox toggles txid=111

<input
    type="checkbox"
    hx-trigger="change"
    hx-replace-url="true"
    hx-get="?accepted=true" />

the above code adds accepted=true params to the url but doesn't remove when checked again.

You can define name and value and htmx will attach them as query param when making GET request.
Try this:
<input
  type="checkbox"
  value="true"
  name="accepted"
  hx-replace-url="true"
  hx-get="/"
  hx-trigger="change"
/>


In case you have multiple checkboxes, you should wrap them with form tag:
<form hx-get="/" hx-trigger="change" hx-replace-url="true">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="accepted"
      value="true"
    />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="excluded"
      value="true"
    />
</form>


Thanks for answering. but your suggestion removes other queries too when unchecked. I have multiple checkboxes that adds different query params to the url. Is this the realm of JS? I am new to HTMX.

If you have multiple checkboxes, you should wrap them with form tag and attach hx-get to the form. I've updated my answer. Please update your question, so it's more relevant to you specific issue.
